# Maintaining multiple build versions of asp .net mssql applications

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, stored-procedures, web-config

We have new versions of .net applications deployed every week for testing given in form of new build files
Can any one suggest how I can maintain many versions of the builds without having to keep many copies of builds and databases

Heres what I have in mind :

- For each build maintain a new folder in inetpub > wwwroot
- Have one database
- Keep mssql stored procedures in same one database in different
  schemas(*) or keep it in local folder drives (*not sure how to do
  this)
- In Web config file point to same database for each of the builds, but
  somehow be able to suggest which build version of stored procedures
  to use for each build from the webconfig (again not sure how to do
  this)

Is this possible and how ? A way of version control and deploy and maintain builds on a single db
Or can anyone recommend other better methods for maintaining multiple build versions, any links or thoughts will be helpful

Comment: I found few refrences, but not sure how much is applicable
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10973/how-can-i-run-multiple-concurrent-versions-of-my-application-against-the-same-da
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/01fc26/how-to-use-stored-procedure-in-simple-easy-way-with-web-config-file/

Comment: Hi guys can anyone give example of how such asp .net applications are deployed or maintained in your companies